# Spring MVC using same path on endpoints to return different content?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm going to use a very basic hello world endpoint as an example

```
 @RequestMapping("/hello")
 public String hello(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("name", name);
     return "helloworld";
 }
```

If I have this endpoint and I want to be able to go to /hello and retrieve the `helloworld` view.

Is it possible for me to use the SAME `/hello` path to retrieve model as json if I pass in a specific request param like content-type?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _model as json_? Are you referring to the model attributes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

If you mean that you want to be able to send a request to `/hello` and get two different responses, with different content types, yes, you can do that.

`@RequestMapping` identifies a method as being a request handler, but it also provides options for restricting when the handler should be used.

In this case, you should use the `Accept` header in your HTTP request and set it to `application/json` for a response containing JSON and `text/html` for a response containing HTML.

You can then have two `@RequestMapping` methods like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", produces = "application/json")
public SomeType handleJson() {...}

@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", produces = "text/html")
public String handleHtml() {...}
```

Spring will determine which method to use based on the request's `Accept` header and the method's `produces` value.

Comment: I had to additionally add the `@ResponseBody` annotation for the json case so the object to json conversion of Spring would kick in.

Answer (score 9):

You could try passing in a parameter using the `RequestMapping` **params** option. This does require modifying the URL, but the mapping is still the same and a mapped method without a params tag could be added as a default.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hello" params= param1)
public returnType method(@RequestParam("param1") p) { ... }

@RequestMapping(value="/hello" params= param2)
public differentreturnType method2(@RequestParam("param2") p) { ... }
```

So to handle the first, request URL : `http://etc.com/hello?param1=x` and the second `http://etc.com/hello?param2=y`.

Params section of `@RequestMapping` docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--