# @RestController class with two @RequestMappings both with same endpoint one with no parameters and one with parameters

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a restful API (using Spring Boot v2.0.0.Release), I want there to be one endpoint but I'd like there to be two possible uses:

```
GET /time - outputs current time (e.g. linux epoch in seconds)
GET /time?delta=100000 (time adjusted by the delta in seconds e.g. +ve=future -ve=past)
```

Firstly is this possible? and secondly does anyone have a code example?

your help is much appreciated

Comment: Just consider `delta` as optional

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your advice, I found that this worked for me.  It needed the defaultValue to be added.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/time",
                produces = { "text/plain" },
                method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getTime(@RequestParam(value = "delta",
                                                     required = false,
                                                     defaultValue = "0")
                                                     long delta) {
    if (0L == delta) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(calcTime(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    else {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(calcTime(delta), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer to just call `calcTime(delta)` and do the different handling of a 0 delta in that method

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. Why dont you make one endpoint with optional parameters?

Check for other answers for similar questions :

[Spring MVC using same path on endpoints to return different content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195162/spring-mvc-using-same-path-on-endpoints-to-return-different-content)

[Two GET methods with different query parameters : REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270475/two-get-methods-with-different-query-parameters-rest)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like with Java 8 and Spring assuming return type String

```
@GetMapping("/time")
public String getTime(@RequestParam Optional<Integer> delta) {
   //...
}
```

or

```
@RequestMapping("/time")
public String getTime(@RequestParam Optional<Integer> delta) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following aside from Java 8's Optional `@RequestParam`: Pass the `required=false` param in `@RequestParam`

```
@RestController
class MyClass {

@RequestMapping("/time")
public MyType myEndpoint(@RequestParam(required=false) Integer delta) {
   // if delta is null then it hasn't been provided
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is indeed possible. It seems like you want a single endpoint but with an optional `delta` parameter.

To achieve this you only need a single @RequestMapping annotation on your method, and all the Spring ceremony goes on the parameter, e.g.:

```
@RequestMapping(value = “/time”)
public TimeResponse time(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer delta) {
     if (delta == null) { 
          // default case
     }
          // case where delta is present 
}
```